# function not reacting

Tags: php, javascript, html, input

I need help with writing a code which will do next.

I have numbers on one side, and when I click on them (they act as link) they are added into input box (in same document, every number has specific box). Then I have a function which reads what is written in that box, uses that value and does some calculations and after it is displaying it on the same page - without refreshing. Everything goes well when I wrote numbers manually, but when I use function

```
function addTextTagF(text){
    document.getElementById('text_tag_inputF').value += text;
}
```

Nothing happens!
I need to make it to react somehow, please help me.

Other used functions:

```
function preview_kopins(currency)
{
    var rate = 0.0025;
    var food = window.document.frm.food.value;

    food = food * rate;


    total = food;

    if(isNaN(total))
        total = "0";

    document.getElementById("pkopins").innerHTML = total + " " + currency;
}
```

Other one

```
<input type="text" id="text_tag_inputF" name="food" size="5" value="" 
    onchange="preview_kopins('<?php echo CURRENCY_NAME ?>');" 
    onkeypress="preview_kopins('<?php echo CURRENCY_NAME ?>');" 
    onpaste="preview_kopins('<?php echo CURRENCY_NAME ?>');" 
    oninput="preview_kopins('<?php echo CURRENCY_NAME ?>');" >

<a href="#" 
    onClick="addTextTagF('<?php echo floor($fcapacity); ?>'); return false">
      <?php echo floor($fcapacity); ?></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you want to add the number to the current number of `text_tag_inputF`?

Try:

```
function addTextTagF(text){
    document.getElementById('text_tag_inputF').value = document.getElementById('text_tag_inputF').value + parseInt(text);
}
```

Comment: This is how table looks like: http://grabilla.com/0320e-30f31fe0-b938-4dd4-afb4-8b8ae31b291e.html

When I click on number on the right - nothing happens (it should calculate and show Total cost at the bottom)